# Does כל האומר דבר בשם אומרו מביא גאלה לעולם apply to all people?

Tags: gentiles, pirke-avot-ethicsof, evil-resha

Does the statement in pirkei avos (6:6) that כל האומר דבר בשם אומרו מביא גאלה לעולם apply if the original author of the statement is a non-Jew? What if the originator is a rasha?